# Xcode 7 Unable to publish iOS app with ITMS-90163 & ITMS-90535

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode7

I get the following errors when I try to publish my app to apple app store.

Error 1:

[image]

Error 2:
[image]

Comment: When asking questions here, ask well organized and clear questions  in order to understand and provide good answers.

Comment: com + f ： Find CFBundleExecutable key , removed from Google Signin SDK with info.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your app uses APNS(Apple Push Notification Service). To use that, you have to make Provisioning profile including aps-environment.

Google "create provisioning profile apns"
https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=create+provisioning+profile+apns&oq=create+provisioning+profile+apns